# winrt how to get files list from device using c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, system.io.file

I need get a list of all files in device (phone or PC) in my universal app. In wpf I did somesing like that:

```
class Collection {
    private StringCollection seachResults; 
    //find all mp3 files in local storage
    private void ScanDrives() {
        seachResults.Clear();
        string[] drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
        foreach (string dr in drives) {
            DriveInfo di = new DriveInfo(dr);
            if (!di.IsReady) {
                //skip if drive not ready
                continue;
            }
            DirectoryInfo rootDir = di.RootDirectory;
            WalkDirectoryTree(rootDir);
        }
    }

    private void WalkDirectoryTree(DirectoryInfo root) {
        FileInfo[] files = null;
        DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;
        try {
            files = root.GetFiles("*.mp3");
        } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e) {

        } catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e) {

        }

        if (files != null) {
            foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in files) {
                seachResults.Add(fileInfo.FullName);
            }
            subDirs = root.GetDirectories();
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs) {
                WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to migrate this into winRT app I get a few errors like `unknown type Drive` and `unexisted method Environment.GetLogicalDrives()`.

Can anyone say how do that in winRT?

Comment: Environment.GetLogicalDrives(); only works in win32 or win64 I believe. Did you try System.IO's GetLogicalDrives()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won’t find a method for getting all logical drives in a WinRT app; WinRT apps exist in a sandboxed environment and will only have access to their own isolated storage or known folders (such as music) if declared as a capability in the application manifest.

For example, to get access to the user’s music folder you can do this (don’t forget to declare the capability in the app manifest):

```
StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
```

The only way to get access to any other part of the file system is if the user specifically grants access via a file picker:

```
var folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
var folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me if media files is stored at flash memory will they be added automaticly into music library (if device is phone)?

Comment: Yes, the StorageFolder returned by KnownFolders.MusicLibrary is a virtual folder, and querying it will return files that are stored on both internal and removable storage.

If, for some reason, the music files you need to access are outside of the standard music folder on the SD card, then you can gain access to the SD card – https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn611857.aspx - but that shouldn’t be necessary if the music is stored in the right place.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives()`?

I believe that Environment.GetLogicalDrives() only works for Win32/Win64. If I am not mistaken System.IO.Directory exists in mscorlib, and is widely available across Phone, RT, or Regular versions.

The MSDN reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getlogicaldrives%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I get an error "directory doesn't exist in System.IO namespace". Project type is Portable class library. I read that in winRT exists Windows.Storage.Folder instead System.IO.Directory but it hasn't some method for getting logical driver.